# C++ Compare two multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

```
unsigned char channeltab1[7][12]; //array which I receive from socket(Array is the same as below)
unsigned char equal_channeltab1[7][12] //arrays which I wants to compare with channeltab1
{
    {0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef},
    {0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef},
    {0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef},
    {0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef},
    {0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef},
    {0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef},
    {0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef},
};
```

I want compare this arrays, but function strcmp work only with one-dimensional arrays.
I try use strncmp:

```
for(int x = 0; x<7; x++)
{
    for(int i =1; x<12;i++)
    {
        if (strncmp (reinterpret_cast<const char*>(channeltab1[x][i]),reinterpret_cast<const char*>(equal_channeltab1[x][i]),2) == 0)
        {
            /*...*/
        }
        else
        {
            /*...*/
        }
    }

}
```

But when application run this instruction says:
Memory fault

If i use:

```
for(int x = 0; x<7; x++)
{
    if (strncmp (reinterpret_cast<const char*>(channeltab1[x]),reinterpret_cast<const char*>(equal_channeltab1[x]),2) == 0)
    {
        /*..*/
    }
    else
    {
        /*..*/
    }   
}
```

They are not the same for program.

What should I do?

Comment: `strncmp` is for strings. Strings end on `\0x0`, which you have in your array.

Comment: Use `std::array` to be able to do `channeltab1 == equal_channeltab1` directly.

Comment: ohh, thx I forgot about this,but which function I can use?

Comment: Just use `==` on the objects themselves in your double-loop code, without trying to cast or to use string functions. That is, `if (channeltab1[x][i] == equal_channeltab1[x][i]) { ... } else { ... }`. Oh, and I guess you want to start the inner loop at `0`, not `1`.

Comment: I would suggest not to use reinterpret_cast if you are not absolutly 100% sure that it will work correctly.
And in your program you can just use `==` operator instead of `strcmp` wich is only for strings - char arrays.

Comment: You're trying to compare a `char` with another `char` in the inner `for`-loop. Why aren't you just doing `if (channeltab1[x][i] == equal_channeltab1)`? Also, take a look at [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) for comparing two iterables.

Comment: Thx guys, I try before with == without loop and because of that I think this don't work.

Comment: `if (memcmp(channeltab1, equal_channeltab1, sizeof(channeltab1)) == 0)` would compare the entire arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"strncmp" is used for standard "C" strings comparsion (or ASCII ones) not for data as it's in your case (data and arrays are always the same in "C++" language). So you should use ['memcpy'](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) instead. So your code will look something like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x<7; x++)
{
        if (memcmp((void*)channeltab1[x],(void*)equal_channeltab1[x], 12 * sizeof(unsigned char)) == 0)
        {
            /*equal*/
        }
        else
        {
            /*not equal*/
        }   
}
```

Comment: You mean memcmp not memcpy

Comment: Yep sorry - just fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Following may help:

```
bool is_equal(const unsigned char (&lhs)[7][12], const unsigned char (&rhs)[7][12])
{
    for (int i = 0; i != 7; ++i) {
        if (memcmp(lhs[i], rhs[i], 12) != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

or even (thanks to Hanno Binder)

```
bool is_equal(const unsigned char (&lhs)[7][12], const unsigned char (&rhs)[7][12])
{
    return memcmp(lhs, rhs, sizeof(lhs)) != 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not `memcmp` the whole arrays? `memcmp( lhs, rhs, sizeof(*lhs))`?

Comment: I believe because 'lsh' & 'rhs' are pointing to the first element of an array of pointers to the first element to array of unsigned chars.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [memcmp](http://pl.wikibooks.org/wiki/C/memcmp)

```
(sizeof(channeltab1) == sizeof(equal_channeltab1)
&& (memcmp(channeltab1, equal_channeltab1, sizeof(equal_channeltab1)) == 0)
```

Note you have to make sure theirs sizes are equal.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to implement a new comparing function rather then trying to use these C functions. You can start from something like this:

```
bool checkEquals(unsigned char** a, unsigned char** b, size_t outterSize, size_t innerSize)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < outterSize; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < innerSize; ++j)
        {
            if (a[i][j] != b[i][j])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::Array`

```
std::array<unsigned char, 7*12> channeltab1;
std::array<unsigned char, 7*12> equal_channeltab1 = {
    0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef,
    0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef,
    0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef,
    0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef,
    0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef,
    0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef,
    0x10, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x02, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x10, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xef
};
```

and to compare, you can now do:

```
if (channeltab1 == equal_channeltab1){
    //do stuff
}
```

note, an `array[x*y]` is the same as an `array[x][y]`

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional arrays are store in continuous memory so actually `memcmp` should work, `memcmp` avoids mistakes in the cast.

```
memcmp(channeltab1, equal_channeltab1, sizeof(channeltab1))
```

Edit: strncmp doesn't work because there could be zero's in the values.